# jQuery Submit POST without form

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to submit a POST to a PHP script, without using a form. The function works correctly apart from the actual post part.

Can anyone see what must be wrong with what I am doing here?

```
function checkforRates(){
alert('activated');
//FUNCTION CHECKS FOR RATES FOR EACH OF THE ICPS IN LATEST CONTRACT
var count = $("#selectICP").children("option:not([disabled])").length;
success = 0
$('#selectICP option:not([disabled])').each(function() {
    opICPs = $(this).val();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        type: 'POST',
        URL: 'functions/workforce_newcontract.php',
        data: {'checkrates': 'true', 'ICP': opICPs, 'ctype': ctype},
        //data: '?checkrates=true&ICP=' + opICPs + '&ctype=' + ctype,
        success: function(result) {
            if(result == 1){    
                //THIS ICP HAS ALL METERS AND ENGINES WITH RATES
                success = success + 1;
            } else {       
                $('#contract_window_message_error_mes').html(result);
                $('#contract_window_message_error').fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut(700);
                return false;
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#contract_window_message_error_mes').html("An error occured, the form was not submitted.");
            $('#contract_window_message_error').fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut(700);
        }
    });
    if(success === count){
        //CONTINUE ONTO NEXT STAGE
        alert('Success!');
    }
});
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What's not working, are there any errors in the console?

Comment: It looks like you are falling into a trap of asynchronous javascript. I believe all your code is working,but your if statement runs before ajax finishes. You should put a few console.log's in your ajax success method. If you can tell that the ajax is not working as expected, please include what the output from the debug console.log's would mean.

Comment: $.ajaxSetup will NOT do the AJAX call, it just prepare for future AJAX call. Try changing it to $.ajax() and run again. Furthermore, AJAX is async. I don't think it can finish earlier than the "if (success === count)" right after the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're calling the wrong function. You need to call `$.ajax()`, not `$.ajaxSetup()`.

Second, you are not providing the correct arguments. Specifically:

```
    URL: 'functions/workforce_newcontract.php',
```

The correct property name is `url`, not `URL`:

```
    url: 'functions/workforce_newcontract.php',
```

Third, as Ken Cheung pointed out, you're not handling the asynchronous part correctly. This bit of code:

```
if(success === count){
    //CONTINUE ONTO NEXT STAGE
    alert('Success!');
}
```

needs to be *inside* your `success()` function, not after the `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: thanks @Michael Geary the capitals did the trick. And thanks everyone else for pointing out the if(success === count) problem :)