# Submit input data without form tag

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am working with a .NET coded online store that uses a form to serve all page content. I need to insert a mailing list signup form on the page, but I can't use the standard format since nested forms are not valid HTML.

My plan was to remove the form tags and submit the data using jQuery, but i'm slightly lost as to how to do so. I know of the jQuery Post/AJAX methods, but i'm looking for some guidance on how to do this.

Also, the form has hidden inputs which is throwing me off.

Any guidance is appreciated. Here is the code:

```
    <form action='//luckyhorngifts.activehosted.com/proc.php' method='post' id='_form_1026' accept-charset='utf-8' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
      <input type='hidden' name='f' value='1026'>
      <input type='hidden' name='s' value=''>
      <input type='hidden' name='c' value='0'>
      <input type='hidden' name='m' value='0'>
      <input type='hidden' name='act' value='sub'>
      <input type='hidden' name='nlbox[]' value='2'>
      <div class='_form'>
        <div class='formwrapper'>
          <div id='_field81'>
            <div id='compile81' class='_field _type_input'>
              <div class='_label '>
                Email *
              </div>
              <div class='_option'>
                <input type='email' name='email' >
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id='_field82'>
            <div id='compile82' class='_field _type_input'>
              <div class='_option'>
                <input type='submit' value="Subscribe">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="preview_part">
          <div id="notice">
            <a href="http://www.activecampaign.com/" title="email marketing" target="_blank">email marketing</a>
            by activecampaign
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: There is something similar to your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149861/jquery-submit-post-without-form

Answer (score 0):

In the jQuery post method that you'll use, append to your `url` parameter the values of the elements you want submitted. Something like:

```
// assuming your fields have id references
var field1 = $("#field1").val();
var field2 = $("#field2").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myServlet?field1="+field1+"&field2="+field2....,
    success: function(data) {
        // do something..
    }
});
```

Comment: `$.post()` is cleaner than `$.ajax()`... Pet peeve of mine